# GRANT statement syntax problems and php, assign privileges

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, checkbox

Hi all I'm trying to make a small program to create a user and assign privileges on the database manager in php

this is the code:

```
 <?php 
$host1='localhost'; 
$user1='root'; 
$pass1=''; 
$conexion=mysql_connect($host1,$user1,$pass1); 
if(!$_POST) 
{ 
?> 
<form id="form1" method="post" action="base.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="text" name="usuario" > Nombre usuario <br> 
<br><b>Datos:</b><br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="insert" value="insert"> Insert <br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="DELETE"> Delete<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="file" value="FILE"> File<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="SELECT" value="SELECT"> SELECT<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="UPDATE" value="UPDATE">UPDATE<br> 
<INPUT name="Registrar" type=submit value="Registrar"> 
<?php 
} 

else 
{ 

$host = 'localhost'; 
$pass = '12345'; 
$user =$_POST["usuario"];
$delete =$_POST["delete"]; 
$file =$_POST["file"]; 
$insert =$_POST["insert"]; 
$select =$_POST["SELECT"]; 
$update =$_POST["UPDATE"]; 

$createQ = "CREATE USER '{$user}'@'{$host}' IDENTIFIED BY '{$pass}'"; 
$grantQ = "GRANT  {$file},{$insert},{$delete},{$selec},{$update}  ON  *.* TO '{$user}'@'{$host}' WITH GRANT OPTION"; 
if(mysql_query($createQ)){ 
    echo 'Usuario creado <br/>'; 
    if(mysql_query($grantQ)){ 
        echo 'Permisos concedidos<br/>'; 
    }else{ 
        echo 'permissions query failed:'.mysql_error().'<br/>'; 
    } 

}else{ 
    echo '<b>El usuario posiblemente ya existe </b>:'.mysql_error().'<br/>'; 
} 
} 
?>
```

The problem with commas (,), if not select a checkbox comma in the sentence is (so would two commas together) and I get syntax error

What can I do then?

I appreciate your prompt help

Cheers

Comment: hopefully only an Admin has access to this !

Comment: harness the power of the `if` statement

Comment: Sorry I do not understand them

Comment: let's say you did not have a comma issue. And anyone on the net can access that php. They could (especially with a robot tool) jam so many users up *&#^^ that you would rather reinstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed very insecure code, I agree with that. But the actual question is how to solve *'the problem with the commas'*, and I'll answer that below. Use an array to store your privilege keywords, and the `join()` function to glue them together with a comma in between:

```
$insert = $_POST["insert"]; 
$delete = $_POST["delete"]; 
$file = $_POST["file"]; 
$select = $_POST["SELECT"]; 
$update = $_POST["UPDATE"]; 

$privs = array();
if ($insert != "") $privs[] = $insert;
if ($delete != "") $privs[] = $delete;
if ($file != "") $privs[] = $file;
if ($select != "") $privs[] = $select;
if ($update != "") $privs[] = $update;

if (count($privs) > 0) {        
    $privclause = join(", ", $privs);
    $grantQ = "GRANT $privclause ON *.* TO '{$user}'@'{$host}' WITH GRANT OPTION";
    }
```

Please also note that if no options are checked, the GRANT statement doesn't have to be executed.

Now, suppose that only the INSERT and SELECT options are checked. The SQL statment will become:

```
GRANT INSERT, SELECT ON *.* TO ''@'' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

And if only the SELECT option is checked, the statement becomes:

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO ''@'' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

The `join()` function will only paste the given string *between* parts, not automatically *before* or *after* parts.

Comment: Thank you gave me a big clue